# how to configure pdo mapping in xdd

Tags: network-protocols, canopen, br-automation-studio

I'm adding pdo object each in eclipse xdd editor.

I looked for documents related to pdo mapping, but there is an error

to be more precise
It is confirmed normally in xdd editor, but an error occurs in B&R Automation Studio

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZaHvc.png)

I added a subobject to the object 2000 & 2100 and
mapped it to the object 1600 & 1A00

I mapped it considering offset,
but I don't know how to reset 32bit of cob-id to zero in eclipse xdd editor

I made it by referring to the following documents
(POWERLINK Controlled Node V3 Protocol API 10 EN)

Thank you for all your assistance